# Crime tv series (older than 10 years) with stone circle

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

I'm looking for **crime tv series** that was **realised between 2000-2008**

**Language**: English

**Country**: UK (not sure)

**Date**: Older than 10 years

I think the main protagonist was female, and she returned to her family town, -
 not sure about the second part tho.

**Plot**: Story was built around stone circle, near this town. Stones had strange symbols engraved on them. I remember scene when those stones started to bleed. They've thought it was paranormal but then protagonist found basments/corridors underneath the stones and everthing occures a hoax.

Other scene I remeber was on graveyard where main protagonist saw a ghost (her mother's maybe?) but that was a hoax too.

In series there was a lighthouse too. There lived a man- seems to was close with protagonist. I think the place was important for the plot. Maybe the underground corridor from circle went there.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: [**Identify-This-X Questions**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be the french serie named "Dolmen", there is a stone which ooze blood.
Year 2005

And the synopsis thanks to wikipedia :

Marie Kermeur, a young police lieutenant, returns to the island to marry her childhood love, Christian Bréhat. But on the day before the wedding of Marie and Christian, strange events begin to happen. The bloody corpse of a seagull is brought in by the tide, Marie is assaulted by strange nightmares during the night, her brother Gildas is found dead, and menhirs near the town begin to ooze blood.
Aided by an inspector from the mainland, Lucas Fersen, Marie decides to clarify these strange phenomena. It is now that a series of deaths begin.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolmen_(miniseries)